# How can I make refresh page button in flutter?

Tags: flutter

How can I make refresh page button in flutter?

```
            new IconButton(
          icon: new Image.asset(
            '../assets/images/iconRefresh.png',
            width: 31,
            height: 31,
          ),
          tooltip: 'Refresh',
          onPressed: iconButtonPressed,
        ),
```

I don't know function of it. Honestly I am a rooky in programming so please help me :)

Comment: What are you looking to refresh with the button? Please provide some more info and code.

Comment: you can use setState to refresh the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Refreshindicator widget 
Below is the sample example

```
RefreshIndicator(
    key: _refreshIndicatorKey,
    onRefresh: _refresh,
    child: ListView(children: [
      // body of above
    ])),
```

And Following is the method on Refresh

```
Future<Null> _refresh() {
  // You can do part here what you want to refresh
}
```

you can check out the complete example in the below-mentioned link:
https://medium.com/flutterpub/adding-swipe-to-refresh-to-flutter-app-b234534f39a7

As you are not clear with what you have mentioned as "button" you can use the setState to make changes.

Answer (score 0):

In Flutter, you can rebuild your Widget very easily. You can just call the `setState` function, and Flutter will run build again. If anything changed in your State, it will be updated. Note that this only works in Stateful Widgets.

```
void updateUI(){
   setState(() {
      //You can also make changes to your state here.
    });
}
```